# When does a game stop being inessential?

Tags: game-theory

This [resource](https://www.jstor.org/stable/30022816) defines an inessential game in the following way:

> An inessential game is an n player cooperative characteristic function game where the total amount to be divided up is less than the sum of the amounts that each player thinks he can obtain when playing alone.

But what if the sum of the amounts the players think they can get is exactly equal to the amount they get from playing the game cooperatively? Surely, in that case, the game is still inessential because there is zero benefit in playing?

Is this the standard way of defining an inessential game in Game Theory?

Comment: If the definition says less than, it means less than. Equal to or greater than are right out.

Comment: I'll rephrase the question.

Comment: Your question was correctly answered. Rephrasing the question without changing it in any substantial fashion does not change that answer. You would have to ask the source why they chose less than instead of less than or equal to, but that is still the definition they made.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I'm trying to query the Game Theory community on the definition. I'd like to know if the source is authoritative. I've updated the question to reflect that. Why do I have to query the source? Surely the idea of an "inessential game" is more broadly used than this single source.